# Is there a int to string format that turns zero into a blank?

Tags: c#, string

I'm displaying int values to the screen as strings, but if the value is zero (or less, I suppose) I want the string to be blank.
To check that I'd need a set of if statements and to store the int value temporarily just to check it (or else retrieve it twice.)
I'm wondering if there is a ToString format that will automatically do that, like how I can use ToString("N0") to add commas.  That way I can just directly set the string value in a single line.

Comment: Have you tried... `string intStringValue = intValue <= 0 ? "" : intValue.ToString("N0");`

Answer (score 1):

I found that 0.ToString("#") results in ""

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The `";"` conditional format specifier will format `positive;negative;zero` values as needed, yielding "blank when zero" functionality. Example one-line usage:

`yourIntVariable.ToString("#;;''");`

Lots of flexibility to format the output, depending on what you formatting option you put in each section.

Full details of how to use this in different scenarios:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--section-separator

Further reading from Rick Strahl:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Jan/05/Blank-Zero-Values-in-CSharp-Number-Format-Strings

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of that functionality:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 5;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("test 1: {0}", x <= 0 ? "" : x));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("test 2: {0}", y <= 0 ? "" : y));
```

Output:

```
test 1: 
test 2: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of an extension method as shown below:

```
namespace System
{
   public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string FormartIntZeroORLessToEmpty(this int value)
        {
            if(value <= 0)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```